# Pagination in feeds like ATOM and RSS?

Tags: atom-feed, rss2

Is this even possible?

Perhaps?

```
<link rel=“next” type=“application/atom+xml” href=”[//path/page2]”></link>
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking here. Could you elaborate?

Comment: I believe he's asking if he can retrieve only from 21-30 feeds, or something like that

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15428056/is-the-atomid-element-unique-per-physical-feed-or-logical-feed

Answer (score 28):

It appears that ATOM [allows the following syntax](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipatom2/) (first Google result for '`ATOM feed next/previous`'):

```
<link rel="self" type="application/atom+xml" href="http://www.syfyportal.com/atomFeed.php?page=3"/>
<link rel="first" href="http://www.syfyportal.com/atomFeed.php"/>
<link rel="next" href="http://www.syfyportal.com/atomFeed.php?page=4"/>
<link rel="previous" href="http://www.syfyportal.com/atomFeed.php?page=2"/>
<link rel="last" href="http://www.syfyportal.com/atomFeed.php?page=147"/>
```

I can't find anything on RSS, but as it's called "**really simple** syndication" I'd imagine such functionality is outside its scope.

Comment: RSS also stands for RDF Site Summary. ;)
There are lots of differences between RSS 1.0 and 2.0 (there actually different standards, not really different versions).

Comment: Actually, it is even recommended to use the <atom:link>s in RSS 2 feeds: https://validator.w3.org/feed/docs/warning/MissingAtomSelfLink.html

Answer (score 20):

This is defined in RFC 5005, Feed Paging and Archiving, [section 3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-3).

You can use first, previous, next and last as a link relation:

```
<link rel="next" href="http://example.org/index.atom?page=2"/>
```

An additional "type" attribute is not needed.

Comment: This is implemented in blogspot.com feed altogether with opensearch tag that shows total count. Unfortunately not all rss readers supports this yet but hope this is a matter of time