# Is the atom:id element unique per physical feed, or logical feed?

Tags: atom-feed

We're breaking a logical feed up over several physical feeds using the "next-archive" and "prev-archive" link relations to tie everything together.

Should each individual feed have its own id, or should the id be constant across the whole series of physical feeds?

[The Atom specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4287) says:

> 4.2.6.  The "atom:id" Element
>
> The "atom:id" element conveys a permanent, universally unique
>   identifier for an entry or feed.

Answer (score 4):

The ID for an entry should be the same across the different feeds it appears in. From the [Atom discussion wiki](http://www.intertwingly.net/wiki/pie/PaceAtomIdDos):

> Restricting the uniqueness scope of atom:id entirely to a single feed would make it much less valuable, since entries are often copied form feed to feed, and sometimes simultaneously published in multiple feeds.

The examples in [RFC 5005](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005) strongly suggest that the separate physical feeds ("archived feeds") should also share an ID to indicate that they belong to the same logical feed.

Comment: You're right, the same id is reused in the RFC 5005 documentation, but it would be nice to have something more explicit.