# RSS.XML Paging like feed/?paged=2

Tags: xml, rss, paging, feed

is there any way to view some site rss.xml like wordpress feed (`feed/?paged=2`)

example : `http://somesite.com/rss.xml`

and i need to see `http://somesite.com/rss.xml` Page 2 , Page 3 and so on

i have try different ways like `http://somesite.com/rss.xml?page=2` and etc but no luck

Answer (score 1):

There is no standard for pagination of RSS feeds and most publishers will actually not have any pagination scheme for this. You're out of luck...

Answer (score 1):

The situation has changed it seems. There is now a standard sor ATOM feeds [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/x-tipatom2/), and as an [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5005#section-3).

Also, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301392/pagination-in-feeds-like-atom-and-rss) question and answers.

Comment: Note the section in the RFC: `3.  Paged Feeds`