# Get number of feed pages?

Tags: wordpress, rss, feed, atom-feed, rss-reader

is it possible to get a number of feed pages or the whole document?

For example I have a feed url like:

> https://www.example.com/feed

and I can get the next page like:

> https://www.example.com/feed?paged=2

but to be honest I do not know how many pages the feed contains.

I would like to iterate for the whole feed.

Comment: Within WP or from the outside?

Comment: @janh From outside.

Comment: Basically, what you want is to iterate over all the pages/articles etc, of your wordpress instance. Don't understand why specifically from the feed. If this is what you need, I can write an answer with WP Query that can fit your needs, just confirm me.

Comment: It is not only applied for the WordPress but the general.

Comment: Feeds do allow pagination, but don't require it, see also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301392/pagination-in-feeds-like-atom-and-rss) for technical details. In your case: increase the parameter until you either get a 404 or no more `<item>`s. Add a hard limit to not run endlessly with broken implementation (maybe compare item links?).